# in laravel Property [password] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-7

hello i use login page for login on my website and where call admin password i see Property [password] does not exist on this collection instance    error

my method when dd password :

```
 public function dologin(Request $request){

    $username = $request->username;
    $password = $request->password;
    $admin = User::with('usermetas')->where('username',$username)->
    orWhere('email',$username)->where('admin','0')->get();
    dd($admin->password);}
```

my users table have a password  varchar(250) colomen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `get()` returns a collection and you need to loop through it to get a property. use `first()` that will return an object to which the property exist.

```
$admin = User::with('usermetas')->where('username',$username)->
    orWhere('email',$username)->where('admin','0')->first();
```